# getting unknown attribute name error but it exist in schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, schema

here are my schema file

```
`create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "name"
end`
```

this is the error:
` _assign_attribute': unknown attribute 'name' for Category. (ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError)

```
      raise UnknownAttributeError.new(self, k.to_s)
```

`
if I create a category instance I got Error

```
category= Category.new(name: "sports")
```

Comment: Has your database been created? Does it have that column?

Comment: Does `Category` inherit from either `ActiveRecord::Base` or `ApplicationRecord`?

Comment: I am using a test case for category which is inherit from ApplicationREcord

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems likely to be a "reload your server and/or rails console" issue. Those are not automatically reloaded to pick up new DB attributes.

Comment: Thanks I restart Visual studio and re run migration , it works.